# NPM Installation failed

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, npm-install

I have downloaded latest version of nodejs for windows.

When I run command `npm install` it install some package and at last it gives me error

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency
>   /chokidar/fsevents:
>
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or
>   architecture:fsevents@1.0.14
>
> npm WARN vue-jwt-auth-example@1.0.0 No repository field.

I am trying to run [Vue.js JWT Authentication](https://github.com/auth0-blog/vue-jwt-authentication)

Please help, to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are warnings, not errors, so everything still should run fine.

`fsevents` is an optional dependency, and because it is not supported by your operating system, it is skipped.

The other warning is related to you not having a repository field in your `package.json` file, so just something to tell you to fix, but not mandatory.

Everything should work fine!